# How to reserve meeting rooms with desktop calender application and Google Calendar

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, google-calendar, evolution

Has anyone been able to set up Evolution or Thunderbird/Lightning so that they can integrate with Google Calendar (in a corporate setting) to reserve meeting rooms? I believe this would require access to viewing the meeting room calendars and sending them iCal invites, but I'm no expert. If you have done so I would love to hear how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and tried doing this with Thunderbird and it seemed like it mostly worked using the [gContactSync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/gcontactsync/) plugin. When scheduling an event, I click on "Invite Attendees" it could auto-suggest contacts and then show me when they're free/busy.

To reserve a meeting room, I was able to find the meeting room's calendar in Google Calendar, then from its calendar settings I could find the calendar ID, which I could then add as an Room.

I haven't yet tried sending an invitation to a group. I expect that it will work but I couldn't see free/busy information for all the people that belong to the group, which is one nice thing from Google Cal.